# Python exec() function broken in versions above 2.7? Error: 'name' not defined

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, exec

I've discovered a strange behaviour of python `exec()` function. Here is the code:

```py
variables = {
    ('foo', 6),
    ('bar', 42)
}

def func():
    for varData in variables:
        varName, varValue = varData
        localVarToEvaluate = varName + ' = varValue'
        try:
            #exec(localVarToEvaluate, globals(), locals())
            exec(localVarToEvaluate)
        except Exception as err:
            print(str(err))

        if varName not in locals():
            print("Variable names '", varName, "can't be found in local scope!")

    if 'foo' in locals():
        print("'foo' OK:", foo)  # exception here
    else:
        print("'foo' not available!")

    if 'bar' in locals():
        print("'bar' OK:", bar)
    else:
        print("'bar' not available!")

func()
```

I would expect variables `foo` and `bar` to be created and printed at the end by `exec()` call, which is the case with Python 2.7. Everything above (tested on 3.3, 3.4, 3.6, and 3.7) throws exception, that `foo` is not defined:

```
Exception has occurred: NameError
    name 'foo' is not defined
```

Strange thing here is that `foo` and `bar` is seen by running `locals()`, `globals()` or `dir()` (also confirmed by `if` statements), however, it is not seen by the code/interpreter. 
Even stranger, debugging this script and resolving any variable is successfull (I've set a breakpoint on `# exception here` and type `foo` in Debug window using VS Code. `foo` is correctly resolved with a value of '6'.

If the same code (stuff inside function `func()`) is not wrapped in function, this works as expected, `foo` and `bar` are printed out.

Any idea what is happening here?

---

**UPDATE:** I've further simplify this problem:

```py
# take 1, create local variable 'foo' with value 6. Not in function.
varName = 'foo'
varValue = 42
localVarToEvaluate = varName + ' = varValue'

try:
    exec(localVarToEvaluate)
except Exception as err:
    print(str(err))

if 'foo' in locals():
    # print(locals()['foo']) # (1)
    # print(foo)  # (2)
    print("'foo' OK:", foo)  # (3)


# take 2, create local variable 'bar' with value 42
def func2():
    varName = 'bar'
    varValue = 42
    localVarToEvaluate = varName + ' = varValue'

    try:
        exec(localVarToEvaluate)
    except Exception as err:
        print(str(err))

    if 'bar' in locals():
        # print(locals()['bar']) # (1)
        # print(bar)  # (2)
        #print("'bar' OK:", bar)  # (3)
        pass # uncomment any line above

func2()
```

When this code executes, first:

```
'foo' OK: 6
```

is printed, than this exception is raised:

```py
Exception has occurred: NameError
name 'bar' is not defined
  ...
```

Note that both codes are identical, except that 'bar' variable is created inside function `func2()`.

What I am interested in are not workarounds but explanation, why is this so and why points (1) works, while (2) and (3) does not. Note that `bar` variable is seen in `locals()`, while it is not accessible by directly calling it - but only if it is created inside function!

Answer (score 1):

[I've reported a bug on a Python Issue Tracker](https://bugs.python.org/issue36426), and the *official* answer is:

> This is currently by design, which means 3.8 is likely the only viable place it can change. It's also not Windows specific so I removed that component (people may remove themselves from nosy).
>   ...
>   Currently it's basically a read-only proxy, as locals are optimized within functions which is why you can't see updates via the duct.

Bottom line, `exec()` used in this way is useless inside functions.

Answer (score 0):

Lots of unclear issues about this question solved with OP. See answer edits. It boils down to (importing) hooking locals (variables, defs, classes) such that they are available for use inside a definition.

See answer below with inline comments what is what and why.

```
# take 1, create local variable 'foo' with value 6. Not in function.

# >>> code is executed in local-scope <<<

varName = 'foo'
varValue = 42
localVarToEvaluate = varName + ' = varValue'

try:
    exec(localVarToEvaluate)    # (0) dict item becomes {varName : varValue}
    print (localVarToEvaluate)  # (1)  prints > foo = varValue < dict item
except Exception as err:
    print(str(err))

if 'foo' in locals():
    print(locals()['foo'])      # (2)  prints > 42             <             value
    print(foo)                  # (3)  prints > 42             <             value
    print("'foo' OK:", foo)     # (4)  prints > 'foo' OK: 42   < stringtext, value


# take 2, create local variable 'bar' with value 42

def func2(self):

    # >>> code executed inside function and not local-scope <<<

    varName = 'bar'
    varValue = 42
    localVar2Evaluate = varName + ' = varValue'

    try:
        exec(localVar2Evaluate)    # (5) dict item becomes {varName : varValue}
        print (localVar2Evaluate)  # (6) prints > bar = varValue < dict item
    except Exception as err:
        print(str(err))

    print ('local-scope :', '\n', locals())  # (7) {'bar': 42, 'localVar2Evaluate': 'bar = varValue', 'varValue': 42, 'varName': 'bar'}

    if 'bar' in locals():
        print(locals()['bar'])     # (1)
        print(bar)                 # (2)  < --- python is not looking here in the locals() but inside the def for variable `bar` which is not made unless you give it access (hook or reference) via e.g. self.
        print("'bar' OK:", bar)    # (3)
       # pass # uncomment any line above

x = 'a scotch... lets drink.. mystery solved!'
bar = "the local 'bar' variable is now available inside def func2()..  It is: %s" % x
func2(bar)
```

As you can see I (import) create a hook to a local variable with varName 'bar' to be used inside the definition using `self`. It can be any name t.b.h. See pydocs on `self`, etc.

The result:

```
bar = varValue
local-scope : 
 {'localVar2Evaluate': 'bar = varValue', 'varValue': 42, 'bar': 42, 'self': "the local 'bar' variable is now available inside def func2()..  It is: a scotch... lets drink.. mystery solved!", 'varName': 'bar'}
42
the local 'bar' variable is now available inside def func2()..  It is: a scotch... lets drink.. mystery solved!
'bar' OK: the local 'bar' variable is now available inside def func2()..  It is: a scotch... lets drink.. mystery solved!
```

If `print('\n\n', locals())` below func() you get the following printresult:

1. 'bar': "the local 'bar' variable is now available inside def
   func2()..  It is: a scotch... lets drink.. mistery solved!"
2. 'localVarToEvaluate': 'foo = varValue'
3. 'varValue': 42
4. 'foo': 42
5. 'varName': 'foo'
6. 'x': 'a scotch... lets drink.. mistery solved!'
7. 'func2': "<"function func2 at 0x000002B070027F28">"  # without " outside ">".

At bullet 7 you see func2 linked.

**UPDATE 4:**

Switching between python 2.7.16 and 3.5.2 revealed no change for the locals() dict and ONE change in the globals() dict as shown below.

In 2.7: `'variables': set([('bar', 42), ('foo', 6)])`

In 3.5: `'variables': {('bar', 42), ('foo', 6)}`

... this `set()` looks to me the reason why it no longer works what you addressed in 3.5.

I did test it with adapting your script:

```
import sys

print (sys.version)

variables = {('foo', 6), ('bar', 42)}

def func():
    for varData in variables:
        varName, varValue = varData
        localVarToEvaluate = varName + ' = varValue'
        try:
            exec(localVarToEvaluate)
            print ('t2\n', locals())
        except Exception as err:
            print(str(err))

        if varName not in globals():
            print("Variable names '", varName, "can't be found in global scope!")

    if 'foo' in globals():
        print("'foo' OK:", foo)  # exception here
    else:
        print("'foo' not available!")

    if 'bar' in globals():
        print("'bar' OK:", bar)
    else:
        print("'bar' not available!")

print ('t1\n', globals())

func()
```

Then ... it could still be exec. So I disabled running `func()` and the difference in `globals()` remained. SO I think its a difference in `globals()` function, rather `exec`.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. Of course `foo` does not exist jet, this is the whole point of doing `exec()`. The interesting part of this code block
```lang-py
if 'foo' in locals():
    print("'foo' OK:", foo)  # exception here
``` 
is that `foo` variable is created and can be seen in `locals()`, but when I try to print it out, interpreter knows nothing about it.
What do you mean by: _... because 'foo' is in your script just a text variable and not a list or tuple container._?

Comment: I've updated the issue description. Note that I'am not interested in workarounds, but in explanation. Thank you!

Comment: Thank you for your effort, but I still don't see how this has anything to do with my question. Why is `exec()` call working outside func2, and why I can see `bar` variable in locals(): `'bar' (1908669175152):42` while python still can't see it?

Comment: I've added a bunch of lines with in a particular execution order. This way you can see that you are still confusing things. In particular, you're mixing up stringtext with variable names in the locals scope. Check the arrow where it goes wrong with your assumption of what you think you are seeing. For more in-depth info check python docs for :variables, objects, pointers, id() and built-in functions. The `getattr` and `setattr` are the right tools to create variables  on-the-fly as the first part of your question pointed towards.

Comment: The second part memory references to variable and not values that are stringtext. The third part answers your local scope issues you thought there were. Conclusion: a name error exception is a variable not defined.

Comment: Of course, I am obviously confused, that is why I wrote this question :) About your response: It makes sense why it does not work: 
In first `try...except` block, `localVar3Evalutate` resolves to a string `'bar = fake-varValue'` which is than `exec()`. Since there is no `fake-varValue` definition, this call obviously fails.
In the second case, error has nothing to do with `exec()`, since it fails before, where `localVar4Evalutate` is defined: you are trying to concatenate string item with integer item - `varName + varValue` which is `bar` + 42. `exec()` call is not even executed.

Comment: Good to read you can reproduce it and see the difference. See the final update for the cherry on the pie :-)

Comment: This was already a response to your latest update. Your code does not make sense - when it fails, it is logically it will fail. My problem on the other hand is related to `exec()` behaving differently inside function than outside of it.

Comment: Now your question makes sense. I've cleared the answered updates to focus solely on the end result.

Comment: Using `self` as a variable name is a bad idea. Syntacticaly it can be done, since it is just a name, but usually `self` is used in class. Your code again is a workaround, not an explanation. What you've done is create a global variable named `bar` and assign `42` to it in `func2()`. That is why it is seen by the interpretter inside `func2()`, where it usually failed for me. If you print `bar` once `func2()` returned, you would still see variable `bar` as: `the local 'bar' variable is now available inside def func2().. It is: a scotch... lets drink..`.

Comment: Also, if I would know variable names in advanced, I wouldn't even need `exec()`. I would just assign their values directly in function: `bar = 42`. I am interested why, once `exec('bar = 42')` in function is executed, `bar` is seen in `locals()` but not by the interpretter.